# change style of Draw and Modify Features openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers-7

I was using **Draw and Modify Features** example of OpenLayers  in the site *https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html*
I was wondering if I could draw features with different styles ?
in other words I need to have two style for my points how can I achieve that ?

```
      <label for="type">Geometry type &nbsp;</label>
      <select id="type">
        <option value="Point1">Point1</option>
        <option value="Point2">Point2</option>
        <option value="LineString">LineString</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: The Draw interaction has a style option, but it only controls what the feature looks like while it is drawing, once it it complete it takes the style of its layer unless you set a style at the drawend event, e.g. https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-and-modify-features-forked-wkfisw?file=/index.html